# Buy 3 items and get the cheapest one free: Magento 2

Tags: magento2, shopping-cart-price-rules, promotions

I'm searching for at solution for being able to sell a customer 3 different product items and then getting the cheapest one for free.   Can I accomplish this through the magento admin or does it require custom coding/extension?   I'm on Magento ver. 2.1.7.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately this would require custom coding or an extension. There is no way to do this in default Magento.

Comment: Any idea who makes an extension that does this or how long it takes to write custom coding for this?

Comment: I haven't used it but I have heard good things about Amasty Special Promotions. I would chat in with them and ask if it can do that.

Comment: Thanks, it looks form their product listing page: https://amasty.com/special-promotions-for-magento-2.html that it does exactly what I want.